# Where is Google Chrome located in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, google-chrome

Is Google Chrome located in `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe`, or is it in `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application`?

A few months ago, a friend of mine said the former. But yesterday, I asked another friend who did a fresh install of Chrome, and she is saying the latter.

Which one is true for Windows 8? Did Chrome change something?

Answer (score 29):

This is what google says on their change to the install directory:

> Actually we did change the download page to install system-level by
>   default (and fall back to user level if that fails or the user says
>   "no" to the UAC prompt). Installing in AppData was never a security
>   measure, it was for convenience to make sure people could install
>   Chrome even without admin rights.
>
> Our data shows that preferring a system level (Program Files) install
>   with a fallback to user level improves the install success rate.
>   - Mark Larson (Google)

**Standard:** C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\

**Fallback:** C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application

Comment: So that means, by default it will be Program Files? And in which version did this change occur?

Comment: Ok, just googled it - https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/chromium-discuss/MrfbaVTH4NM  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting. Wasn't aware this change had happened